# Task Scheduler is not poping up WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I want to pop up a WPF window in every 5 minutes. My OS is Windows 7 and C# is 4.0. I thought of writing a Windows service. But later came to know that Windows services cannot poped up any Window. Then I tried with task scheduler.

I created a WPF Application with only 1 window. Then I went to Task Scheduler (control panel – > Administrative tools – > Task Scheduler – > Create Task). There I specified all the required parameters for running the WPF application exe for every 5 minutes. But window is not poped up. And it shows the task is running in the All Running Task list control. What could be the problem?

Which is the best way to pop up a WPF window every 5 minutes daily?

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is subjective, but I would create a [NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) that stays resident in the taskbar and uses a DispatchTimer to open windows or do whatever every 5 minutes. If you need to launch the program automatically at logon time you can just drop a shortcut into your user profile's startup folder. The main advantage of this approach is that your program can continue doing background stuff all the time and it's easy to change the popup frequency via a simple context menu if you need to.

As to why the Task Scheduler approach isn't working, I would check to make sure you've configured the task to only run when the user is logged on. Tasks will run in a non-interactive session otherwise.